# Установка Windsor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, как установить виндсор для ASP.NET MVC Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На официальный сайт не заглядывали? Там все есть. Ссылка на серию уроков, от самых азов -
научиться: [Windsor tutorial - ASP.NET MVC 3 application](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx).

Comment: спасибо,молодой человек

Comment: Пожалуйста.

Comment: что то мне не удается добавить эти сборки в GAC. утилита не GACutil открывается и тут же закрывается. что же сделать?

Comment: Зачем их в GAC ставить? Но если хотите, то нужно запустить командную строку VS: в меню пуск найдите Visual Studio, затем Tools, затем Command Promt (это для английской версии). И там вбивайте такую команду: `gacutil.exe /i *путь к сборке*`